# Como pegar altura de uma div por jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, div

Estou com um pequeno script jQuery para ao carregar a página, é feito um cálculo baseado na altura de uma `div` e depois adiciona-se uma margem pelo resultado obtido.

O problema é que não está pegando o valor da altura dessa `div`. No caso, não existe CSS pré-determinando a altura dela, então a altura varia de acordo com seu conteúdo.

Código jQuery que estou usando:

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
    var alturaDivTxt2 = $(".slide-txt").height();
    var autoH2 = $(".autoH-banner").css("height");
    var alturaDoBanner2 = (autoH2.replace("px","") / 2) + 60;
    var alturaTxtFinal2 = alturaDoBanner2 - alturaDivTxt2;
    alert('div: '+alturaDivTxt2+' banner: '+alturaDoBanner2+' final: '+alturaTxtFinal2);

    $(".slide-txt").css({ "margin-top": +alturaTxtFinal2+"px" }); 
});
```

*Coloquei aquele `alert` apenas para visualizar se os dados estavam sendo processados corretamente.*

O valor da `alturaDivTxt2` retorna **zero**.

O que pode estar errado? Eu já tentei por essa function dentro do `$(document).ready()` mas mesmo assim não funciona. Também já tentei usar `.innerHeight()` e outros derivados, sem sucesso.

Comment: Em vez de `$(window).load` mude para `$(document).ready` ou `$(function(){/*seucodigo*/});`

Comment: Eu já tentei usar dentro do `$(document).ready`, mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: tenta recuperar dessa forma http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/4sc0pm4w/

Comment: @DiegoVieira Também não deu. :(

Comment: Faça as seguintes verificações no código HTML, a div possui a classe ".slide-txt"? Verifique também através do inspecionar elemento se a div possui altura.

Coloque a estrutura do código HTML se possível, também o css que correspondem as divs isso pode ajudar.

Comment: Está tudo certo. Tem um exemplo aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/jhcapr0n/. É estranho, pois re-utilizo esse mesmo código com o `$(window).on('resize', function(){` e funciona.

Comment: Existe mais algum elemento com a classe `slide-txt`?

Comment: Não, é uma `div` somente usada no banner do site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

utilize `setTimeout` no seu código para que de tempo do mesmo renderizar e executar.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    var alturaDivTxt2 = $('.slide-txt').height();
    var autoH2 = $(".autoH-banner").height();
    var alturaDoBanner2 = (autoH2 / 2) + 60;
    var alturaTxtFinal2 = alturaDoBanner2 - alturaDivTxt2;

    $(".slide-txt").css({ "margin-top": +alturaTxtFinal2+"px" });
}, 600);
```

Answer (score 2):

peguei seu codigo e mexi um pouquin só, troquei aquele replace que estava quebrando e peguei o autoH2 por .height() e aqui funcionou direitin, se não consegui te ajudar, comente aqui que tentarei te auxiliar melhor ^^

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var alturaDivTxt2 = $('.slide-txt').height();
    var autoH2 = $(".autoH-banner").height();
    var alturaDoBanner2 = (autoH2 / 2) + 60;
    var alturaTxtFinal2 = alturaDoBanner2 - alturaDivTxt2;

    console.log('div: '+alturaDivTxt2+' banner: '+alturaDoBanner2+' final: '+alturaTxtFinal2);   
});
```

Comment: Realmente o `replace` não é tão útil, obrigado. Maas.. infelizmente não funcionou :(

Comment: Leia isso daqui, talvez possa te ajudar.
http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

Answer (score 0):

Tente com isso aqui:

```
var alturaDivTxt2 = $(".slide-txt")[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

**Update:**

Use o método window.getComputedStyle, esse método retorna todo o CSS computado:

```
var div = $('.slide-txt')[0];
var alturaDivTxt2 = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(div).height);
```

Comment: Não, continua retornando altura zero. :(

Comment: Você pode por no Codepen.io com o HTML e CSS?

Comment: Então, http://jsfiddle.net/jhcapr0n/ aqui está. O curioso é que funcionou!! Do jeito que eu estava fazendo.... Estranho demais. Será que é porque essa `div .slide-txt` fica dentro de uma outra `div` que está sendo usada em um slideshow?

Comment: Por isso que pedi para você colocar o CSS, eu acredito que essa div possui elementos com float será necessário o uso de um clearfix.

Comment: O curioso é que eu re-utilizo o mesmo código com o `$(window).on('resize', function(){` e funciona. No caso o mesmo código é executado quando o site é aberto, e depois quando tem redimensionamento da janela.

Comment: O jQuery já usa o `getComputedStyle` internamente.

Comment: coloca um settimeout de 1 segundo em seu código e veja se ele aplica o que você deseja, caso funcione é por que ele não está aguardando até o fim da renderização do código. @Ricardo

Comment: @DiegoVieira coloquei e não deu também. Abre o site com o `slide-txt` lá no topo, depois de 1seg ele executa a função e dai é dada a `margin-top` errada, como antes. Não está pegando a altura da `div` mesmo! :\

Comment: Deu!! \O\ Ajustei o timer e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Sugestão do colega @DiegoVieira, que foi adicionar um `setTimeout` ao código, pois provavelmente ele está sendo executado antes de todo o conteúdo do site estar carregado, principalmente a `div` que estou utilizando.

Então, o código corrigido e funcionando ficou assim:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    var alturaDivTxt2 = $('.slide-txt').height();
    var autoH2 = $(".autoH-banner").height();
    var alturaDoBanner2 = (autoH2 / 2) + 60;
    var alturaTxtFinal2 = alturaDoBanner2 - alturaDivTxt2;

    $(".slide-txt").css({ "margin-top": +alturaTxtFinal2+"px" });
}, 600);
```

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Disponha! Irei postar como minha resposta ok?

Comment: Pode postar sim :)